# Chrome isn't displaying borders (sometimes)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, border

So, my site (www.around-around.com), has a lot of borders and they work fine on Safari, FF, and IE; but on Chrome, occasionally, they disappear. I've searched through the code and it doesn't make sense to me.

If you go to http://www.around-around.com/8/ on FF, you'll see the borders around the article. But on Chrome, they disappear.

The relevant CSS is:

```
#page {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border-left: 1px dotted #222222;
border-right: 1px dotted #222222;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1148px;
}
.singular #primary {
margin-bottom: 0;
padding: 0 0 20px 20px;
width: 787px;
border-right: 1px dotted #222222;
float: left;
}
```

(and #primary)

I'm totally baffled. On other pages, such as http://www.around-around.com/dream-perfume/ , Chrome displays the borders fine. The code is exactly the same - the only difference is the post content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are hitting http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=32702

**EDIT**:

The bug has been fixed, verified against Chromium [src@139014](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/detail?r=139014)! Should go live in Chrome 21.

Comment: I think you're right Alexander. Thanks. I'm going to follow that thread and hopefully they'll figure it out. What a dumb problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, too.
Chrome didn't seem to like this.

```
{border: <size> <style> <color>;}
```

It only worked if I put the parameters in separately like this.

```
{
    border: <size>;
    border-style: <style>;
    border-color: <color>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Year 2023 but I still get this bag on client notebook on latest Chrome 110.0.5481.178

Answer (score 0):

because default border-style in Chrome is "none".
for each border attribute in Chrome you must assign border-style value.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently (Chrome 72), long after the bug was marked as resolved in the Chromium project. Disabling hardware acceleration solved the issue.